# Why is WordPress changing my HTML code

Tags: css, html

I've been playing around with CSS and HTML code and I finally got to the point where the section I was working on works.  I saved my CSS, and updated my post, and everything looked great, but when I returned to the post and switched from the HTML tab to the Visual tab WordPress altered/deleted my HTML code.

I re-entered my HTML code in the post, saved it while still in HTML view and the post appears exactly the way I want it to look.

[My Post](http://www.bornsquishy.com/about-me/gene-find-project-results/) - The Bobby Ore quote is what I was working on.  I saved/updated while still in HTML view, so the code appears to work.  Here's the HTML code that I entered into the HTML view of my post:

```
<p class="space"><quote class="open">&#8220</quote><quote class="font">Forget about style; worry about results.</quote><quote class="cite">~ Bobby Orr</quote><quote class="close">&#8221</quote></p>
```

After switching to the Visual tab and back to the HTML tab, the HTML code now looks like this:

```
<p class="space">&amp;#8220Forget about style; worry about results.~ Bobby Orr&amp;#8221</p>
```

Help???

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

1. You're missing the semicolon after your unicode character, should be `&#8221;`
2. The `quote` element gets stripped by the visual editor b/c the version of TinyMCE that Wordpress implements is only set to recognize a certain subset of html elements and it strips out the rest.

Possible solutions:

1. Disable the visual editor in your user profile: Users > Your Profile > Disable the visual editor when writing.
2. If you still need your visual editor then apply your styling to one of the allowed HTML elements, like `<p class="cite">`.
3. Use a background-image or sprite to place the quote marks in the background of an allowed element.
4. Use a plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-valid-elements/) to add the `quote` element as a valid element in TinyMCE.

Comment: Thanks for both responses.  Chazbeaner --> very detailed... helped tons.  Going via option 4.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE (the visual editor) allows just a restricted set of HTML elements and tries to fix everything else. Made up elements like `quote` are stripped to guarantee valid HTML.

Comment: My next question is there anything wrong with making up an element like I did?

Comment: @Bryan Yes, it is semantically meaningless, because no one knows what it stands for. There is no difference between `<quote>` and `<humptydumpty>`. And why would you want to use an element `humptydumpty`? ;)

Comment: Thanks toscho.  I understand what you mean.  I'm really new to CSS.  I ended up using <font> and the classes that I created.